# Mi calculadora no suma mas de dos números

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Mi proyecto de calculadora no opera de manera secuencial, es decir, cuando le mando a que me sume 2 + 3 + 4, me suma 3 + 4, omite el primer digito.

Desde la calculadora se ingresan los números mediante botones con el mismo método desde 0 al 9:

```
public void escribirCero(View view) {
    double valor = Double.parseDouble(tvResultado.getText().toString());

    if(valor == 0) {
        tvResultado.setText("0");
    } else {
        tvResultado.setText(tvResultado.getText() + "0");
    }
}
```

Este método es el identificador de todas las operaciones y se repite el mismo para sumar, restar, multiplicar, dividir y sacar el porcentaje:

```
public void opSuma(View view) {
    numero1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tvResultado.getText()));
    operacion = "+";
    tvResultado.setText("0");
}
```

Este método se efectúa cuando presionamos el botón "=" para conocer el resultado de las operaciones:

```
public void mostrarResultado(View view) {
    numero2 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tvResultado.getText()));
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
    double result = 0;

    if (operacion.equals("%")) {
        result = (numero1 / 100) * numero2;
    } else if (operacion.equals("/")) {
        if (numero2 != 0) {
            result = numero1 / numero2;
        } else {
            result = 0;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opción no válida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else if (operacion.equals("X")) {
        result = numero1 * numero2;
    } else if (operacion.equals("+")) {
        result = numero1 + numero2;
    } else if (operacion.equals("-")) {
        result = numero1 - numero2;
    }

    tvResultado.setText(result + "");
    tvResultado.setText(String.valueOf(nf.format(result)));
    numero1 = 0.0f;
    numero2 = 0.0f;
    operacion = "";
}
```

Lo que se busca es que al nosotros enviar mas de dos números, por ejemplo, 2 + 3 + 4, la calculadora opere con los tres y envíe el resultado de esa operación utilizando los tres números.

Comment: Si tú tienes n números, ¿Por qué solo sumas numero1 + numero2? Podrías utilizar un `for` para sumar tus números.

Comment: En el condicional `if (operacion.equals("/")) {` le faltaría un `else`, para mantener la lógica que tienes. Por otra parte deberías recuperar el contenido del `textView` y hacerle un `split` buscando las operaciones para ir realizándolas una a una.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo podrías especificar a nivel de código, por favor

Comment: El cambio que te sigería es este: `if (operacion.equals("/")) {` por este `else if (operacion.equals("/")) {` en lo referente a tu problema, he intentado solucionarlo, pero no vero como insertas consecutivamente dos operaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Yo separaría el problema en los dos objetivos que debemos conseguir.

Primero, debemos saber cuáles van a ser las operaciones que se van a realizar dentro del conjunto de la operación (es decir, los operadores: + - * /) y almacenarlos en un array de String para su posterior uso y lo mismo con los operandos.

Esto podemos hacerlo de la siguiente manera: (suponiendo que toda la operación se encuentra en la misma línea: 95 + 14.5 / 5)

```
String operacion = textView.getText(); //texto recogido de la interfaz de usuario
String regexOperadores = "\\s*[0-9]+"; //expresión regular para sacar los operadores
String[] operadores = operacion.split(regexOperadores); //recogemos los operadores haciendo split sobre la operación previamente declarada
String regexOperandos = "\\s*[+-/\\*]+"; //expresión regular para sacar los operandos
String [] operandos = operacion.split(regexOperandos); //recogemos los operandos aplicando la expresión regular
```

Una vez hecho esto, que  a mi parecer es lo más complicado, debemos realizar la operación para devolver el resultado correcto. Se me ha ocurrido que podría ser una función de este estilo:

```
private double realizarOperacion(String[]operadores,String[]operandos) {
    //declaramos la varibale que se devolverá y almacenamos el primer número en ella
    double resultado = Double.parseDouble((operandos[0]);
    //recorremos los arrays con un for
    for (int i = 0; i < operadores.length; i++) {
        //vemos cuál es el operador que toca
        switch (operadores[i]) {
        case "+":
            //en caso de que sea una suma sumamos
            resultado += Double.parseDouble(operandos[i]);
            break;
        case "-":
            //en caso de que sea una resta restamos
            resultado -= Double.parseDouble(operandos[i]);
            break;
        case "/":
            //en caso de que sea una división dividimos
            resultado /= Double.parseDouble(operandos[i]);
            break;
        case "*":
            //en caso de que sea una multiplicación multiplicamos
            resultado *= Double.parseDouble(operandos[i]);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Operando no válido")
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }
    //devolvemos el resultado
    return resultado;
}
```

Espero que te sirva la respuesta!

Te recomiendo mirarte a fondo las expresiones regulares y la manipulación de Strings ya que son muy útiles! ;)

Mucha suerte y a seguir programando!